# Can't execute ionic app on deivce

Tags: cordova, ionic3

Whenever I try to deploy my ionic app on my phone I get this error message. It's so long I can't fit here, so I put in online.

I tried reinstalling plugins, platforms, cordova, and ionic itself, but nothing seems to work. It started when I tried to deploy it and I accepted to update ionic from 3.19.1 to 3.20.0.

[Error log](http://hamdanihamza.eb2a.com/error.html)

Answer (score 0):

Umm a lot of resources can't be loaded thou, the app is deployed.
Looks like gradle has been updated with new info so please check if you also have updated all instances of andorid studio (SDK and platform).

Comment: I did what you told me and it didn't work :/ i get this message which i don't understand 
`Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

        at build_jz0bu04gs71jd2xwff2aht1l.run(C:\Users\Hamza\Desktop\ionic\Wydad2\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:143)
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.`

Answer (score 0):

i actually fixed the problem, the cordova facebook4 plugin isn’t compatible with cordova android 7 that i had installed so i installed android 6.4 instead and its working perfectly now !